# How to dismiss popup by clicking inside the popup?

Tags: android, popup

I have a popup and I want to dismiss the popup by clicking inside the popup instead of outside.

I tried to search for the solution to this problem but couldn't find it.

Comment: A popup what, exactly? `PopupWindow`? `PopupMenu`? Some kind of `Dialog`? In any of those cases, the solution is basically the same: set an `OnClickListener` on the desired `View` in the popup, and call `popup.dismiss()` in `onClick()`.

Comment: You should always add your work so far on the problem. Not just the issue you are facing. Seeing what you have already done, someone can give a solution exactly to it. Otherwise they have to imagine a part and implement a solution, which sometimes may not address your exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way. just call the parent layout of your dialog and put set an OnClickListener to that particular parent layout and inside the listner just close the dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Just Use OnClickListener() there is no other solution for that.
your dialog name.onclicklistener and inside that just call dialog.dissmiss.